# This can fail some time? UDP socket listen at INADDR_ANY and sending at 127.0.0.1

Tags: sockets, udp

I was trying to send data via udp socket and client is :

```
sock.sendto(msg, ('127.0.0.1', 5055))
```

while server is listening the same as:

```
 si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
 si_me.sin_port = htons(5055);`enter code here`
 si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
 if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen)) == -1)
```

can this be failed some time as on one machine I am not able to receive any data?

Comment: UDP can fail any time, but there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this code. Post the receiving code.

Comment: @EJP: This is the receiving code.

Comment: @SanjayMishra: on the server side, you are populating `si_me`, so make sure you are passing it to `bind()` before you start calling `recvfrom()`: `bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &si_me, sizeof(si_me));`  And make sure that you are setting `slen` to `sizeof(si_other)` every time you call `recvfrom()`.

Comment: So post the sending code. @RemyLebeau tks.